# Using TFIDF on multiple columns independently

Tags: python, vectorization, multiple-columns, text-classification, tf-idf

I want to classify data into categories basis the information present in 2 different columns. I want to apply TFIDF vectorisation to the two columns independently - i.e. have separate vectors for the information present in the 2 columns and transform the 2 test data columns separately as well.

This is the code that I am using for vectorising only one column (VLOB_D&B) -

```
Train_X, Test_X, Train_Y, Test_Y = 
model_selection.train_test_split(Corpus['VLOB_D&B'],Corpus['category_id'],test_size=0.3, stratify = 
Corpus['category_id'])


Tfidf_vect = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, min_df=2, ngram_range=(1, 2))
Tfidf_vect.fit(Train_X)
Train_X_Tfidf = Tfidf_vect.transform(Train_X)
Test_X_Tfidf = Tfidf_vect.transform(Test_X)
```

I do not want to concatenate the information as the two columns hold different significance. How can i apply TFIDF vectorisation independently on separate columns?

Comment: If you want to use the information from both columns then you must concatenate the features obtained from TfidfVectorizer. If you don't want to concatenate them, then you can only do two independent models.